# Amazon Linux Instance dies in Python script using subprocess.run

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services

I am trying to run a few commands on an `Amazon Linux 2016.09 c4.xlarge` through the `subprocess` module.

I can't use `chef` or other `CM tools` because I don't know the commands prior to running the script.  My script parses an XML report that's output from a CIS security tool.

On one instance, after trying following statements , I got the error:

```
executing command  chown root:root /etc/cron.daily
executing command  iptables -P INPUT DROP
executing command  yum -y install aide

# then crashes: terminal freezez and instance is inaccessible over port 22
```

On another trial the offending yum call is

```
executing command  chown root:root /etc/cron.daily
executing command  iptables -P INPUT DROP
executing command  yum -y remove xorg-x11*
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package xorg-x11-font-utils.x86_64 1:7.2-11.5.amzn1 will be erased
---> Package xorg-x11-fonts-Type1.noarch 0:7.2-9.1.5.amzn1 will be erased
--> Processing Dependency: xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 for package: 1:java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.131-2.6.9.0.71.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64 1:1.7.0.131-2.6.9.0.71.amzn1 will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved
# then crashes: terminal freezez and instance is inaccessible over port 22
```

The script itself is:

```
class CommandFix(object):

    def _execute_command(self):
        for command in self.commands:
            command = command.replace('#', '')
            command = command.replace('yum', 'yum -y')

            print("executing command", command)

            self.stdout_log.write("fixing {} : running command {}\n".format(
                self.rule_id,
                command))

            try:
                cp = subprocess.run(command,
                    shell=True, check=True
                    )
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
                self.stderr_log.write("error fixing {} : {}\n".format(
                    self.rule_id,
                    e))

                # TO-DO: Handle error with retry or similar
                # right now just return false
                return False

        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to close your subprocess .

Try add below lines in your code -

```
import os
process_execution_status = False
try:
    #your code
    process_execution_status = True
catch Exception as exc:
    #exc handling
    process_execution_status = False
finally:
    os.killpg(os.getpgid(cp.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
    return process_execution_status
```

Comment: I think you're right! I will try this now and report back here

Comment: The answer was staring us in the face! iptables! I was blocking myself out

Comment: ohh ok but I reckon it is important to close your subprocess also . please upvote it if you find it useful!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the `iptables` command.  It was dropping all inbound connections.  The instance was fine, just blocked by iptables